# Strange Laptop battery and ac adaptor behaviour with confusing messages

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, battery

I am having strange battery behaviour problems on Win 7. I don't know where to start but three scenarios happen.

Scenario 1: Laptop says Battery not detected yet unplugging Ac adaptor it still remains on.

Scenario2: Laptop says plugged in not charging removing AC adaptor the laptop turns off.

Scenario 3: Laptop says unknown remaining and does not detect AC adaptor.

Any thoughts on diagnosing what is wrong with the computer. The messages and scenarios are pretty random. Also the laptop will not power on only on battery.

All these problems started after installing Virtual Box. Uninstallation hasn't helped improve the situation.

Also the battery and charger are original that came with the box OEM.

Comment: Please add the fact that it is OEM to your question. I am deleting my answer as it is not correct. :)

Comment: The fact uninstalling `VirtualBox` didn't solve the issue proves that `VirutalBox` isn't the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if it was Virtual Box fault or not but the drivers on my computer started to play up. This included keyboard, wifi, networking and battery drivers as well. So I had to launch startup repair and restored by system to an earlier restore point and voila. Everything started working again.